# Webpack bundle validates but node server throwing syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am using webpack to bundle/transform jsx.

From the command line I'm running "webpack --watch". This creates my bundle without errors. Here's my webpack config and Application.js

```
'use strict';
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    devtool: 'eval',
    entry: './client.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname+'/build/js',
        filename: 'client.js'
    },    
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css' },
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'jsx-loader?harmony' }
        ]
    }
};
```

---

```
var React = require('react'),
    classSet = require('react/addons'),
    Nav = require('./Nav.js'),
    Home = require('./Home.js'),
    Recipe = require('./Recipe.js'),
    RecipeArchive = require('./RecipeArchive.js'),
    About = require('./About.js'),
    Timestamp = require('./Timestamp.js'),
    RouterMixin = require('flux-router-component').RouterMixin;

var Application = React.createClass({
    mixins: [RouterMixin],
    getInitialState: function () {
        this.store = this.props.context.getStore('ApplicationStore');
        return this.store.getState();
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        var self = this;
        self._changeEventListener = function () {
            var state = self.store.getState();
            self.setState(state);
        };
        self.store.on('change', self._changeEventListener);
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.store.removeListener('change', self._changeEventListener);
        self._changeEventListener = null;
    },
    render: function () {

        return (
            <div>test</div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Application;
```

---

Then I'm running my node server which throws an error.

```
node server.js
```

results in:

```
/Users//Documents/routing/components/Application.js:39
        <div>test</div>
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

How should I be running my project to allow me to include jsx/harmony in my .js files?

---

---

**UPDATE: Solution**

As Brandon pointed out, I needed to use node-jsx for transforms in Node. At the top I've of my server.js file I've added and alls working:

```
require('node-jsx').install({ extension: '.js', harmony: true });
```

Comment: can you post your `Application.js` (or whatever your jsx code looks like)? Your webpack configuration looks fine

Comment: I added Application.js. I'm confused as to why node is even finding the syntax error if I'm serving the bundle: res.write('<script src="/public/js/client.js" defer></script>');

Comment: `<div>test</div>` should be a string `"<div>test</div>"`

Comment: I added this to the first line of server.js and then it worked.. Don't add it at any random line number.. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack just creates a client-side bundle; when you run your Node app, it doesn't use webpack to load the files. Prevously you could use something like [node-jsx](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-jsx) to require JSX files in Node.js, but that project has since been deprecated in favor of [Babel](http://babeljs.io/). In particular, [you can use `babel-register`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/) to require JSX files in Node.

Comment: Thanks this is all making so much sense now. I'm building off an isomorphic example using yahoo's fluxible-app/routr/fetchr and I just wasn't up to speed on some of the webpack/node/jsx particulars

Comment: @Michelle node-jsx is deprecated can you please suggest another way?